# What anchor cms version page contains?

Tags: version, anchor, anchor-cms

Who can help me, with what the  page version contains?

> https://anchorcms.com/version
> i found the link in update.php

```
/**
 * Holds the AnchorCMS update check URL
 */

const UPDATE_URL = 'https://anchorcms.com/version';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the project AnchorsCMS is shut down because the initial developer has sadly passed away, the development team has decided to take everything offline and stop the development.

The contents of that file was just a blank page with the version of the latest release. The latest release before take down is 0.12.7.

If you want a release check that works, you need to change the URL in the update.php file in the libraries folder to a URL that just displays "0.12.7". If you want you can use mine at https://1ago.be/version-anchorcms

Kind regards,
Pieter